# I want to change caret position in textarea wrapping lines

Tags: javascript, position, textarea, word-wrap, caret

I want to change caret position in textarea wrapping lines to move up/down over lines as in keyboard up/down keys using javascript.

Comment: Please, append your code in the question.

Comment: I don't have any code please help me